# sum for datetime.time dataset

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to sum `data1`, which is pandas.core.series.Series.

```
data1:

0        00:06:44
1        00:00:34
2        00:02:32
3        00:00:18
4        00:03:42
5        23:59:58
```

total = sum(df.data1)
But, I got an error like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-128-9cc06aed3448> in <module>()
      4 
      5 #print(df.data1)
----> 6 total = sum(df.data1)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.time'
```

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1):

There is problem `sum` of `datetime.time`s is not implemented in python, so possible solution are convert values [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html)s first:

```
total = pd.to_timedelta(df.data1.astype(str)).sum()
print (total)
1 days 00:13:48

print (int(total.total_seconds()))
87228
```

Or use `generator` with `sum` components of times:

```
total = sum(x.hour *3600 + x.minute * 60 + x.second for x in df.data1)
print (total)
87228
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this calculation with `pandas`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['00:06:44', '00:00:34', '00:02:32' ,'00:00:18',
                            '00:03:42', '23:59:58']})

res = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']).dt.seconds.sum()  # 87228
```